# Run an ABCL code that uses cl-cppre

Tags: java, lisp, common-lisp, abcl, cl-ppcre

With reference to my previous question,
[Executing a lisp function from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087811/executing-a-lisp-function-from-java)
I was able to call lisp code from Java using ABCL.
But the problem is, the already existing lisp code uses CL-PPCRE package.
I can not compile the code as it says 'CL-PPCRE not found'.
I have tried different approaches to add that package, 
including
1) [how does one compile a clisp program which uses cl-ppcre?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369183/how-does-one-compile-a-clisp-program-which-uses-cl-ppcre)
2)https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cl-ppcre/juSfOhEDa1k

Doesnot work!
Other thing is, that executing (compile-file aima.asd) works perfectly fine although it does also require cl-pprce

```lisp
(defpackage #:aima-asd
(:use :cl :asdf))

(in-package :aima-asd)

(defsystem aima
  :name "aima"
  :version "0.1"
  :components ((:file "defpackage")
           (:file "main" :depends-on ("defpackage")))
   :depends-on (:cl-ppcre))
```

The final java code is

```java
interpreter.eval("(load \"aima/asdf.lisp\")");
interpreter.eval("(compile-file \"aima/aima.asd\")");
interpreter.eval("(compile-file \"aima/defpackage.lisp\")");
interpreter.eval("(in-package :aima)");
interpreter.eval("(load \"aima/aima.lisp\")");
interpreter.eval("(aima-load 'all)");
```

The error message is

```
Error loading C:/Users/Administrator.NUIG-1Z7HN12/workspace/aima/probability/domains/edit-nets.lisp at line 376 (offset 16389)
#<THREAD "main" {3A188AF2}>: Debugger invoked on condition of type READER-ERROR
  The package "CL-PPCRE" can't be found.
[1] AIMA(1):
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please show the exact error message that you're getting;  copy and paste it from the terminal/REPL/etc.  Is it that a *package* isn't found, or a *function*, or something else?

Comment: I Just did. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used QuickLisp to add cl-ppcre (because nothing else worked for me).
Here is what I did

```
(load \"~/QuickLisp.lisp\")")
(quicklisp-quickstart:install) 
(load "~/quicklisp/setup.lisp")
(ql:quickload :cl-ppcre)
```

First 2 lines are only a one time things. Once quickLisp is installed you can start from line 3.

Comment: There is also `ql:add-to-init-file`, which adds Quicklisp to the CL implementation's iinit file so that it is automatically loaded on startup.

Answer (score 2):

You need to load `cl-ppcre` before you can use it.  You can do that by using `(asdf:load-system :aima)`, provided that you put both aima and cl-ppcre into locations that your ASDF searches.

Comment: I was finding it very confusing and techy to do it, it was giving me errors, so i used QuickLisp, loaded quicklisp.lisp and used the statement:  interpreter.eval("( load \"aima/quicklisp.lisp\")");
         interpreter.eval("(load \"aima/quicklisp/setup.lisp\")");
        interpreter.eval("(in-package :ql)");
        interpreter.eval("(ql:quickload :cl-ppcre)");

Comment: @HamdaBinteAjmal, you should post that as an answer; it's a pretty good solution.  (I think the in-package part is redundant, though.)